# Archer GRC Test Automation with Selenium

Tags: ui-automation, rsa-archer-grc

Has anyone implemented Automated Testing with Selenium on Java for Archer GRC ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was successfully implemented in the company I work for.
Users interact with is HTML-based forms, they can be tested with Selenium.
Some pages on the back end (Administration) are still Silverlight-based, that is something Selenium can't test (unless you use image recognition I guess?).